# Why does PHP JSON Response starts with string(###)

Tags: php, json, parsing

I know this might seem like a ridiculous question but I can't figure out why the JSON response I receive starts with the following string(###){ }

```
 string(124) "tonce=1111111111111111&accesskey=2222222-4444-4444-bbbb-777777777777&requestmethod=post&id=1&method=getMarketDepth2¶ms=" {"method":"getMarketDepth2","params":[],"id":1}{ string(672) "{"result":{"market_depth":{"bid":[{"price":3500,"amount":7.198},{"price":3496,"amount":1},{"price":3495.5,"amount":0.02},{"price":3494.99,"amount":13},{"price":3492.81,"amount":1.21},{"price":3492.04,"amount":10},{"price":3492,"amount":6.561},{"price":3489.82,"amount":1.7},{"price":3489.81,"amount":31.8},{"price":3489.61,"amount":0.59}],"ask":[{"price":3510,"amount":166.405},{"price":3518.98,"amount":1.39},{"price":3519,"amount":24.002},{"price":3519.96,"amount":10.958},{"price":3519.98,"amount":0.09},{"price":3520,"amount":116.277},{"price":3520.1,"amount":5},{"price":3522,"amount":43.451},{"price":3522.79,"amount":0.002},{"price":3523,"amount":46.5}]}},"id":"1"}"
```

Was there a particular way I was suppose to parse this or do I just remove everything before the starting and ending curly braces

Here's the code output.

```
 try {      
      $ticker = request('getMarketDepth2', array());
      var_dump(request('getMarketDepth2', array()));
 } catch (Exception $e) {
      echo "Error:".$e->getMessage();
 }
```

Comment: Can you post your `json` file here ?

Comment: Where is your code, post it here.

Comment: That's not JSON, plain and simple. If that is what you are receving, you need to take it up with whoever you're receiving that response from. The latter part is JSON, but the response as a whole isn't; whoever is sending that to you is lying if they're claiming to send JSON.

Comment: The 'string(124)' part is telling you that whatever you are outputting (variable etc) is a string, of 124 length. The parts between the "" are the value of that string.

Answer (score 3):

It's outputting the string(#length) { } because you're using var_dump(). Try using echo instead.